# Objects as Arguments to Python Multiprocessing Pool default to Same Object Memory (Error)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to pass in objects as parameters to a function where I want to use pythons multi-processing pool to execute each of the functions in parallel. However, each of the multi-processing function calls only call the last object in the list.

Each of the printed objects in doSomething() are using the same Temp() object, and have the same memory address. The input temp objects are all unique, but multi-processing pool seems to be only using the last object for each doSomething() function call. Each doSomething() has the same Temp() object.

Why is this happening? How can I properly pass each object into the multi-processing pool to execute in parallel?

```
def doSomething(temp):
    print(temp)

class Temp():
    def __init__(self, b):
        self.a = 10
        self.b = b

def main():

    # Create the input args into the multiprocess pool map function
    temps_args = ()

    bs = [-5, -10, -15]
    for b in bs:

        temp = Temp(b)
        print(temp)
        temps_args += (temp,)

    # Setup multi-procesing pool and execute multiprocessing cases
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    res = pool.map(doSomething, temps_args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: They're not actually the same object - keep in mind that each instance of `doSomething` is running in a separate process, with an entirely separate memory space.  Since all of the memory spaces start out as clones of each other, it's not surprising that the args object received from the main process ends up at the same address in each process.  If you also did `print(temp.b)` in the function, I'm pretty sure you'll see that they're receiving distinct objects, even though their string representations are identical.

Comment: Why do you think they are the same object?

Comment: You are right, it is printing something different for these temp objects.

For the real problem where the object is more complicated (a tree, full of nodes), the multi-processing function call utilizes the same object in each function call, whereas the inputs are all unique objects. Any hints/pointers as to why this may be the case?

Comment: Add a `__str__` or `__repr__` to `Temp` and you will see its all fine.

Answer (score 0):

When the process that runs your function is created, it will start with its own memory based on the current state of the parent process. In the multiprocessing a single process might be re-used many times to reduce startup times. In the case of 3 records, it's very likely that they all hit the same process.

**Before continuing:**

When a Python object is garbage collected, the id for that object goes back into circulation. Take this for example:

```
class Foo:
    pass


# All instances of Foo are kept in memory before ids are fetched
ids_for_alive = set(id(foo) for foo in [Foo() for _ in range(1000)])
print(len(ids_for_alive))
# prints 1000

# After every call to id, the last Foo instance reference is dropped and may be gc'd
ids_for_gc = set(id(Foo()) for _ in range(1000))
print(len(ids_for_gc))
# usually prints 1
```

For me, this just printed `1000` when the object was kept in memory, and only `1` when no references to the objects were kept. They were allowed to get garbage collected, meaning the id kept becoming available, and a single id was re-used consistently 1000 times.

**Back to multiprocessing:**

When the worker is tasked with a job and receives its argument, they are loaded into memory and assigned an id. When that job is over, the reference to the argument, meaning it can get garbage collected, and made available again. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val


def get_id(foo):
    print(foo.val)
    return id(foo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    foos = [Foo(i) for i in range(3)]
    ids = set(pool.map(get_id, foos))

    print(f"Total ids: {len(ids)}")
```

For me this printed:

```
0
1
2
Total ids: 1
```

Now an interesting thing you can do (which is not efficient at all) is to limit the number of jobs that a single process is allowed to do. If you set this value to 1, you will get a new process per call to the task, and very likely a new address space and set of id values.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(maxtasksperchild=1)

    foos = [Foo(i) for i in range(3)]
    ids = set(pool.map(get_id, foos))

    print(f"Total ids: {len(ids)}")
```

prints:

```
0
1
2
Total ids: 3
```

Hope that helps clear things up!